# Renko Chart in R

Tags: r

I am trying to construct Renko Chart using the obtained from Yahoo finance and was wondering if there is any package to do so. I had a look at the most financial packages but was only able to find Candlestick charts.

For more information on Renko charts use the link given [here](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:chart_analysis:renko)

Answer (score 4):

Really cool question! Apparently, there is really nothing of that sort available for R. There were some attempts to do similar things (e.g., waterfall charts) on various sites, but they all don't quite hit the spot. Soooo... I made a little weekend project out of it with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot).

---

## `rrenko`

There are still bugs, instabilities, and visual things that I would love to optimize (and the code is full of commented out debug notes), but the main idea should be there. Open for feedback and points for improvement.

> **Caveats**: There are still case where the data transformation screws up, especially if the size is very small or very large. This should be fixable in the near future. Also, the `renko()` function at the moment expects a dataframe with two columns: `date` (x-axis) and `close` (y-axis).

### Installation

```
devtools::install_github("RomanAbashin/rrenko")
library(rrenko)
```

### Code

```
renko(df, size = 5, style = "modern") + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 150, 10)) +
    labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image: 1]

```
renko(df, size = 5, style = "classic") + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 150, 10)) +
    labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image: 2]

### Data

```
set.seed(1702)
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2014-05-02"), as.Date("2018-05-04"), by = "week"),
                 close = abs(100 + cumsum(sample(seq(-4.9, 4.9, 0.1), 210, replace = TRUE))))

> head(df)
         date close
1: 2014-05-02 104.0
2: 2014-05-09 108.7
3: 2014-05-16 111.5
4: 2014-05-23 110.3
5: 2014-05-30 108.9
6: 2014-06-06 106.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm R investment developer, I used some parts of Roman's code to optimize some lines of my Renko code. Roman's ggplot skills are awesome. The plot function was just possible because of Roman's code.

If someone is interesting:

https://github.com/Kinzel/k_rrenko

It will need the packages: xts, ggplot2 and data.table

"Ativo" need to be a xts, with one of columns named "close" to work.

EDIT:

After TeeKea request, how to use it is simple:

"Ativo" is a EURUSD xts 15-min of 2015-01-01 to 2015-06-01. If the "close" column is not found, it will be used the last one.

```
> head(Ativo)
                       Open    High     Low   Close
2015-01-01 20:00:00 1.20965 1.21022 1.20959 1.21006
2015-01-01 20:15:00 1.21004 1.21004 1.20979 1.21003
2015-01-01 20:30:00 1.21033 1.21041 1.20982 1.21007
2015-01-01 20:45:00 1.21006 1.21007 1.20978 1.21002
2015-01-01 21:00:00 1.21000 1.21002 1.20983 1.21002
2015-01-02 00:00:00 1.21037 1.21063 1.21024 1.21037
```

How to use krenko_plot:

```
krenko_plot(Ativo, 0.01,withDates = F)
```

[Link to image krenko_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETKHw.png)

Compared to plot.xts

```
plot.xts(Ativo, type='candles')
```

[Link to image plot.xts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKOKa.png)

There are two main variables: size and threshold.

"size" is the size of the bricks. Is needed to run.

"threshold" is the threshold of new a brick. Default is 1.

The first brick is removed to ensure reliability.

Comment: You should better show how to use that code here rather than posting a link to it.

Comment: @TeeKea thank you for your comment. I will do it. I'm new here.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution, adapted from a python script [here](https://cryptodigestnews.com/renkotrading-660d9f64c904).

```
# Get some test data

library(rvest)
url <- read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20170602&end=20181126")
df  <- url %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame()

# Make sure to have your time sequence the right way up

data <- apply(df[nrow(df):1, 3:4], 1, mean)

# Build the renko function 

renko <- function(data, delta){
  
  pre <- data[1]
  xpos <- NULL
  ypos <- NULL
  xneg <- NULL
  yneg <- NULL
  
  for(i in 1:length(data)){
    increment <- data[i] - pre
    incrementPerc <- increment / pre
    pre <- data[i]
    if(incrementPerc > delta){
      xpos <- c(xpos, i)
      ypos <- c(ypos, data[i])
    }
    if(incrementPerc < -delta){
      xneg <- c(xneg, i)
      yneg <- c(yneg, data[i])
    }
  }
  
  signal <- list(xpos = xpos,
                 ypos = unname(ypos),
                 xneg = xneg,
                 yneg = unname(yneg))

  return(signal)
  
}

# Apply the renko function and plot the outcome

signals <- renko(data = data, delta = 0.05)

plot(1:length(data), data, type = "l")
points(signals$xneg, signals$yneg, col = "red", pch = 19)
points(signals$xpos, signals$ypos, col = "yellowgreen", pch = 19)
```

**NOTE**: This is not a renko chart (thanks to @Roman). Buy and sell signals are displayed only. See reference mentioned above...

[image]

Comment: Don’t Renko charts have an irregular x axis?

Comment: Correctly detected - anyway, renko is actually based on absolute price gains and losses, not on a percentage (i.e. alpha) like shown above. This would lead to uniformly shaped boxes, where the next box is drawn only when a certain price gain or loss is reached - which on the other hand leads to an irregular x-axis when this is represented by time...